# How do I get to open my page in a new window using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

From my controller A, I'm doing the following -

```
  $window.open("/signals", "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
//$location,path("/signals");
```

My routeprovider configuration is as follows -

```
.when('/signals',{
                templateUrl: 'app/views/signals.html',
                controller: 'signalsCtrl',
                controllerAs : 'signals'
            })
```

My signalsCtrl controller is using a service that returns a list of images that has to be displayed in a new window - signals.html:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('signalsCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$log', 'criteriaService',
        function ($scope, $log, criteriaService) {
            var signals=this;
            signals.getUrls = function(){
                return criteriaService.getUrls()
            };
        }]);
```

signals.html just loops through the list using ng-repeat and displays the images.

The issue is that when I used $location.path("/signals"), it works fine as a new page opens up in the same window (redirection) when I click a button on my parents page. But with $window.open it does not work at all. I do not see my controller (SignalsCtrl) being triggered at all when I try to access this page using $window.open("/signals").

How can I get this to work?

I considered using a modal also but then I need to have the modal stay open all the time while the user can work on the parent page. Modals however do not allow this. And so I am trying to create a new page in a new window but that doesn't work either.

Any pointers here will be really appreciated.

I see that we are reseting the session when a page loads. Since window opens a new page, session is being reset and due to that it goes back to the main page so that user can select criteria again.

```
 this.login = function (credentials) {alert("called login from loginController");
        AuthService.login(credentials).then(function(principal){
            selectionCriteria.clear();
            sessionService.reset();
            $location.path('/');
        }, function(){
            login.error = true;
        });
    }
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you using html5mode in routing config?

Comment: No, the modules that I am using in my app are - 'ngRoute', 'ngCookies', 'cfp.hotkeys','metricatorModule','ngIdle'])    And in the routing config I have $routeProvider, $httpProvider,KeepaliveProvider

Comment: Then that url is meaningless and you need to pass in path with proper route. Your app is using `/#/` in angular routing. Also needs to be absolute enough to locate the index.html

Comment: I didn't get you. Could you please provide an example probably in the answer mode since it will be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: You need a full url to open the window. A new window doesn't know about your angular routes until the new page loads

Comment: I did a $window.open("http://localhost:8070/#/signals")  but it just opens http://localhost:8070/#/

Comment: Actually it does route to http://localhost:8070/#/signals and then re-routes to http://localhost:8070/#/ for some reason.

Comment: Basically it does not invoke the signalsCtrl at all

Comment: Can't help..don't know what's in your app. Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors in the console

Comment: Its weird. When I first click the button that is supposed to open the new page, it gets redirected to localhost. When I go back to the parent page and click the button again, it opens the signals page. But even then, it is not able to access the criteriaService objects

Comment: What else can I add in this question to add more clarity?

Comment: What are you trying to use it for? Not hard to share data across controllers

Comment: Sharing data across controllers is working with the criteriaService and when I use location.path('/signals'). Challenge begins when I try to use $window.open.. I also tried doing what is mentioned in this blog - http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2014/08/19/how-to-open-async-calls-in-a-new-tab-instead-of-new-window-within-an-angularjs-app/    Did not help

Comment: I just want the new window to use the controller - signalsCtrl

Comment: New window and modal are not the same things. You can easily add an element anywhere in the view that uses a controller. Objective is still not clear at all. You have been asking about modals and asking about windows. As for new window I don't know why you are not succeeding there. Something in your app routing is changing to default route for some reason it sounds like.

Comment: Yes, that's happening.

Comment: well that is something inside the app that isn't shown. A resolve or something like that perhaps..or route change event handler.

Comment: Just made one more edit at the bottom of the summary

Comment: Would need to use something like postMessage API to get user data from other window . Or sessionStorage perhaps. I'm guessing if you reload the main page you also end up back needing to log in again

Comment: No I do not have to login again, it just gets redirected to the main page

Comment: Ok.. same thing sort of. Problem is the login logic and or session storage

Comment: Yeah it gets redirected to main but page it still is logged in.

Comment: Completed the app config code in the summary if that provides any more pointers.

Comment: Not really ... issue has to do with how your authservice works in conjunction with the part you just removed for the route change event

Comment: Yup. I just edited end of the summary again to point out the code where sessionService is being reset such that all user specific objects are set to null. What happens is that because of that, it redirects to the main page.

Comment: May be some sort of condition that says that if location.path('signals'), do not reset session....??? or another option - to use a modal or if there is any other way to make a popup. The only requirement there is that it should not render the parent page unaccessible if it is kept open. What do you think?