# Is there a way to open a new window in angularjs without using $window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there anything that can be done with $location object instead of $window?

Comment: [Something like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099784/open-links-in-new-window-using-angularjs)

Comment: Hmmmm close, but my problem is mentioned more in detail here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807549/how-do-i-get-to-open-my-page-in-a-new-window-using-angularjs